# Allowing access to redis port for only specific servers on Windows

Tags: redis

Redis is install in a remote server. my application is hosted in two remote servers. i need to setup to access redis server by only from these two servers. What should i do for that..please anyone recommend suggestions..

Answer (score 1):

Well, to protect your Redis, there are many way to reach that.

1. Use Nginx to proxy and filter IP.
2. Also you can active your password function to protect your Redis.

Comment: ok. but is there anyway to configure on redis.conf to allow to access by some specific servers only?

Comment: And I don't want to specify bind 0.0.0.0. When I try that and restart redis server, I get the following error.   " Windows could not start the radis service on local computer. Error:1067: The process Terminated unexpectedly "